# Replace a string across entire dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many features and I know from ad hoc checking that many of them contain the value "NULL" which I would like to replace with NA.

I know that I can use str_replace column by column, my question is, is there a short hand e.g.

```
mydf <- mydf %>% str_replace_all("NULL", NA)
```

For example:

```
example_mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(disp, wt, qsec), funs(as.character(.)))
example_mtcars$disp[c(2,4,8)] <- "NULL"
example_mtcars$wt[c(10, 12)] <- "NULL"
example_mtcars$qsec[c(2,3,4)] <- "NULL"
```

What is the shortest, least code way to replace all instances of "NULL" across the entire data frame example_mtcars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way -

```
example_mtcars[example_mtcars == "NULL"] <- NA
```

Comment: Isn't that what you want? You want to convert "NULL" to NA, right?

Comment: D'oh! Yes. It's been a tough work day I'm sorry about that. Accepting this answer and deleting my comment shortly

Comment: @DougFir don't beat yourself up about it. I vaguely recall  that this assignment method hasn't always worked for data frames

Answer (score 0):

Shree's solution is fine, but below is the general technique you'd want to use to apply a function to every column of your data frame.

```
mydf <-
    1:ncol(mydf) %>%
        map_df(function_to_apply_to_col())
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner with function `is.na<-`.

```
is.na(example_mtcars) <- example_mtcars == "NULL"
```